# How to change text colors in python 2.7.3

Tags: python, colors

I want to change the color of a text . Of course I don't want to make a GUI for my program. I want to do that just for Terminal . As an example please change this :

```
print("Hello SO !")
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python) might help you.

Comment: You can use the [`colorama`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) module.

Answer (score 4):

1. Install `pip install termcolor`
2. Run this code:

   ```
   from termcolor import colored
   print(colored("Hello world in red style!", 'red'))
   ```
3. use windows powershell or unix shell

Comment: this code not working on windows machine, it printed **←[31mHello world in red style!←[0m**

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ANSI color codes](http://pueblo.sourceforge.net/doc/manual/ansi_color_codes.html). Unfortunately, I believe this only works on Linux-based systems.